# For Loop : increment a long number retaining 0's in php

Tags: php, for-loop

How to increment through LONG number in PHP, for example counter starts from 0000000001 and ends 0000000010, how to loop through in a for loop retaining the zero's.
I do not want to pad 0's in front of the number, because I can increase the number limit to 9999999999999.

```
for ($i=0000000001; $i<=0000000010; $i++) {
echo $i;
}
```

Output:
0000000001
0000000002
0000000003
0000000004
0000000005
0000000006
0000000007
0000000008
0000000009
0000000010

Can someone please help me.

Comment: if you don't want to pad 0 then why you are using `$i=0000000001`. you can use simple as `$i=1`

Comment: Saitsh, I want to increment along with 0.. and go upto the highest number.

Answer (score 2):

You can use [str_pad](http://php.net/manual/en/function.str-pad.php):

```
str_pad($value, 8, '0', STR_PAD_LEFT);
```

OR if it's just for output:

```
sprintf('%08d', 1234567);
```

OR

```
echo str_pad($value, 8, '0', STR_PAD_LEFT);
```

**EDIT**

```
for ($i=1; $i<=10; $i++) {
    echo str_pad($i, 10, '0', STR_PAD_LEFT);
}
```

Comment: But, if I increase the counter in that case 0's will get appended even if I do not want it.

Comment: Just edited my answer, to your specific problems. Please tell me if it still doesn't work and what you get from it..

Comment: This will work until I reach 0000000010,  but if I want 0000000011 then this will fail..

Comment: Well, I tested it in [phpfiddle](http://phpfiddle.org/) everything works fine.. So, if you're saying that you it fails on `$i = 11` then the error must be from somewhere else.. If you don't mind, please copy my code in the **EDIT** part into a new PHP file and test it out..